# Jackson json mapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am farily new to the Jackson json classes. I have just donwloaded version 2.2.1 which seems to be the best version for the jdk 1.5 which is what we have.

I have some json that I am trying to parse nicely but would like some help on how to use the jackson classes. Can someone please help me with an example of how I could map the data into a java object?

Here is my json...

[{"status":"GREEN","businessDate":"2014-07-25","transactionCount":510620},{"status":"GREEN","businessDate":"2014-07-24","transactionCount":532435},{"status":"GREEN","businessDate":"2014-07-23","transactionCount":379355},{"status":"GREEN","businessDate":"2014-07-22","transactionCount":321474},{"status":"GREEN","businessDate":"2014-07-21","transactionCount":322975}]

Here is what the call on my server classes looks like...

```
    String requestURI = "http://mycompany:9080/ReportingManager/service/repManHealth/importHistoryTrafficLightStatus.json";
    URL url = new URL(requestURI);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // do some mapping here...
```

thanks

My question is can I use the jackson

Comment: Whoa! You can drop almost all of that code, and just use:

MyType bean = mapper.readValue(url, MyType.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyObject obj = mapper.readValue(sb.toString(), MyObject.class);
```

When MyObject is implemented in Bean Standard and the attribute names match the attribute names in JSON. All should work fine.
Otherwise use annotations to mapp your java object attributes correctly to the json attributes.
Thats all.

Comment: thanks your answer gave me the solution. Of couse because I had a list I used the readValues method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson mapps the json objects to beans or pojos. You need to setup the beans having the fields like status, businessDate etc. For different names use annotations. And than you can use mapper to map the json string.

Using mapper your code looks like following

```
mapper.readValue(jsonString, YourBean.class);
```

Note here YourBean will be the POJO for holding json data.